# Database Index files get corrupted if shared folder resides in Win Server 2012 but not if it resides in a regula Win 7 PC Shared folder

Tags: database, corruption

Database application programmed for peer to peer access to a shared folder experiences database associated index files corruption if said shared folder resides in Win Server 2008 or Win Server 2012.  If same application share folder resides on a regular Win 7 PC the application runs fine with no Database Index files corruption.  Database tables are currently accessed by 10 Win 7 64bit computers concurrently.

Comment: Please explain all the troubleshooting steps you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and Thanks for your reply;

Application was originally running in Delphi 6 with Apollodb 7.5 and ISAM Clipper NTX tables without any trouble. Very small Medical Office application with no more than 15k patients (and even smaller reference and associated tables) running in 43 offices.  No code modifications, we just upgraded to Delphi XE8 with Apollo 9, recompiled and ever since, the indexes get disorganized and some of the tables can't be open after 4-5 users log in.  After reading every article available we decided to experiment with SMB1/SMB2 and Optlocks without success.  If we run in a shared folder Win 7 32bit pc as the file server it works fine.  The problem has been isolated to appear when we set up the application Win Server 2012/2008 shared folders.  No client server, plain peer to peer.  Haven't get a reply from Apollo, a support ticket is open since 12/18/2016. Have been experimenting with Client/Server test applications using Apollo Database Server, but with such small tables the peer to peer scenario surprisingly works faster.  Again, Thanks for your reply.....